# Header file for functions inside of a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header

In C++ I have a file A.cpp that has the following in it:

```
 namespace Foo {

     bool Bar() 
     { 
         return true; 
     }

 }
```

How would I declare this function in A.h? How do I handle the namespace?

Comment: Gee, I wonder what the answer is. :)

Comment: Yet another StackOverflow meme in the making?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
namespace Foo {
  bool Bar();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
namespace Foo {
    bool Bar();
}
```

Comment: +1 for being character for character the same as John Dibling's answer with the same time stamp (rounded to the minute)

Comment: It's not actually. sharptooth spent 4 seconds on those two extra space characters and a newline. 45wpm... weak.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Foo {
    bool Bar();
}
```

Or

```
/* don't look -- I must have been dreaming or mis-remembering -- the following does NOT work */
namespace Foo;
bool Foo::Bar();
```

Comment: You can use namespace Foo {} to wrap declarations and definitions in as many places as you want. It basically adds "Foo::" to the front of the name of everything inside the brackets. Things not inside a namespace that you name are in the default global namespace.

Comment: Nice second example.  I'd never considered that approach.

Comment: Nice second example. Shame it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Foo {
    bool Bar();
}
```